# Помощь новичку с адаптивной версткой

Tags: вёрстка

Какие @media оптимальнее всего использовать для mobile fist и обычной верстки.
Хотелось бы таргетить смартфоны, планшеты и ПК.

Пока есть что-то типа:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { ... }
```

С переходами на 768px 480px и 320px.
Правильно ли я понимаю что для mobile first нужны те же точки в обратном порядке и

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Методом проб и ошибок было определено:
Точки пресечения определяются зависимо от контента. Тоесть, открываем роботу и уменшаем окно и смотрим, при каких пикселях нужно что-то менять.
Пример: ( Google Chrom ) `Ctrl+Shift+I` затем `Ctrl+Shift+M`, ставим Responsive и в перед.
И собрал для себя Sass документ, соответствие реальным устройствам. Доставив { } где необходимо, можно смело использовать.
Делюсь: https://github.com/vdodovych/WebTemplate/blob/master/src/sass/_media.sass

**P.S. Надеюсь, был кому-то полезен.**